# How to center one div and have another div float left to it?

Tags: html, css

This is what i have now and it works pretty well until you zoom in - https://jsfiddle.net/6mjrjayh/1/

HTML

```
<div id="box1">
<p><strong>About me</strong></p>
<img src ="images/hack.jpg"/>
<p><strong>Image Courtesy Bob Marley</strong><br></br>
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></p>
</div>

<div id="box2">
<p>
Hi there!
<br></br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
<br><br><br>
</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box1 {
  float: left;
  position:absolute;
  padding-left:50px;
}

#box2 {
    width: 20em;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
}
```

I want it so when u zoom in/out box1 keeps its exact position relative to box2 like it is now without zooming. Sorry if i'm not explaining it right but Riot Zeast Captain nearly has got it the way i want except box2 changes its position while box1 retains it whereas i want it the other way around when i zoom in/out of the page.

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of what exactly you want.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check it.

Comment: Imagine my box1 and box2 only had a padding of 5px to each other. No matter how big or small the resolution this does not change. And i want box2 to be centered at all times while box1 is just floating to the left of it. It;s not something i can really screenshot because it's a responsive design issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.boxes{
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
#box1{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: calc(100vw / 4);
}
#box2{
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div id="box1">
    <p><strong>About me</strong></p>
    <img src ="images/hack.jpg"/>
    <p><strong>Image Courtesy Bob Marley</strong><br><br>
      <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></p>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <p>
      Hi there!
      <br><br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
      <br><br><br>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the working code as your required output, but its not responsive.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j39qqdfn/) link

Comment: Ok this ones pretty close but when u zoom in box2 changes its position while box1 retains it. Is there a way to do it the other way around?

Comment: I just spent months on my website that's almost complete. Is there no way to achieve this without learning bootstrap?

Comment: Update your website link, and the problem part too. @user3619057

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```css
  

 #box1 {
  float: left;
  position:absolute;
  padding-left:50px;
}

#box2 {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20em;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box1">
<p><strong>About me</strong></p>
<img src ="images/hack.jpg"/>
<p><strong>Image Courtesy Bob Marley</strong><br></br>
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></p>
</div>

<div id="box2">
<p>
Hi there!
<br></br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
<br><br><br>
</p>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I added position:fixed; and z-index:99; to your code.
Are you looking for this ?

```css
#box1 {
  float: left;
  position:fixed;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:50px;
  border:solid 1px red;
  background-color:red;
  z-index:99;
}

#box2 {
    width: 20em;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
    border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <p><strong>About me</strong></p>
  <img src ="images/hack.jpg"/>
  <p><strong>Image Courtesy Bob Marley</strong>
  <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></p>
</div>

<div id="box2">
  <p>
  Hi there!
  <br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  I'm bob, a freelance designer and developer<br>
  <br><br><br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it so when u zoom in/out box1 keeps its exact position relative to box2 like it is now without zooming.

Comment: @user3619057 what do you mean zooming ? do you mean  scrolling page ?

Comment: It's hard to explain. Look at Riot Zeast Captains code. That guy has it pretty close but box2 changes its position while box1 retains it whereas i want it the other way around when i zoom in/out of the page.